# Cannot run ionic 2 project on Windows while project created on Mac

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

My team and I are currently working on an Ionic 2 project (version 2.1.1) which is stored in Github in the purpose of version control, source code management and share related tasks. My project is created on a Mac platform while one of my teammate is using Windows. When he clones my project and runs it, He's not able to run with the following errors, whilst the others using Mac also are able to run.
So I have a doubt, is it the problem of OS (Mac, Windows) or I am confusing ?

This is the System Information of my team:
[image: System Information]

Errors we got on Windows when he serves and runs the project:
[image: Errors info on Windows]

PS: I got stuck in this for 4 days in a row now, any ideas or suggestion is much appreciated. Thank you for spending your times :)

Comment: Try running `npm install` in the current directory after deleting `node_modules`.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug of ionic-app-scripts on windows.

Comment: Create a new project on windows and copy over all app/ files and package.json etc